# How to populate a hashmap from an array

Tags: java, android, hashmap

i have two arrays (actually one, but i created two for each columns). I want to populate a hashmap with the values for a listview but all elements of the listview is the last element of the arrays:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

    for (int i=0; i<13; i++)
    {
        map.put("left1", date[i]);
        map.put("right1", name[i]);
        mylist.add(map);
    }


SimpleAdapter  simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist, R.layout.row,
        new String[] {"left1", "right1"}, new int[] {R.id.left, R.id.right});
lv1.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);
```

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: You should consider declaring your variable using just the interface, as opposed to restricting it to the concrete implementation. 'List<Map<String,String>> myList' would be better.

Comment: Actually, it should probably be `List<? extends Map<String,String>> myList` (and `Map<String,String> map`). There's an argument to be made, though, that every variable should be declared as the most specific type it is known to be. Under that criterion, the declarations are good as they stand because they are local to the function. (As parameters, the same criterion dictates that they should be declared to be the most general type acceptable, since that's all that needs to be assumed about them.) Besides, this way it saves an import or two. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're adding the same map to every slot of the array. Try this instead:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

for (int i=0; i<13; i++)
{
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("left1", date[i]);
    map.put("right1", name[i]);
    mylist.add(map);
}
```

Comment: +1: And this is why you have to be careful where you put your variable declarations!

Comment: what do you mean? I tried to declare the arrays both in the oncreate method, both outside it, like  String[] date = new String[13];

Comment: @erdomester: In your original implementation, you have one map already created. Then, you're going through the loop and and putting differing values, but the same key every time (overwriting it, of course), which is why it ends up with the last value in the array. @Ted Hopp's method creates a new map each time the loop runs, and adds that map with the key and value to your array.

Comment: I would have never thought of this. I like and know arrays better :) Thank you!

Comment: Btw how can i remove the items from the listview? I have googled several topics, and there is no clear() or remove() command for the adapter even if a lot of people say so..

Comment: Did you look at the documentation for [SimpleAdapter.remove()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#remove(T))?